# Asp.net core 2.0 mvc view throws err on long datatype

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Have an asp.net core 2.0 mvc app.  All views in this controller, except Create, are throwing the following error on a field w a long datatype.  Other controllers/views work fine.

[image: asp.net core error]
Here's the model...

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Check your database schema - what datatype this field has - `int` or `bigint`? May be you changed datatype in one place and does not changed in other?

Comment: DataType is long.  It may have originally been int but it was so long ago I don't remember.  Regardless it needs to be long. Sql type is int but according to the documentation it covers the range of a c# long type.

Comment: What documentation you ar looking in? `bigint` in TSQL is mapped to `long`, `int` to `int` AFAIK.

Comment: guess I goofed that one, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Changing db type to bigint fxd problem.